# Strange javascript / json error after server migration

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsonp

I have a website hosted on server A that sends a request to a website on server B.

The website on server B has recently seen moved to another server. Lets call that server C.

Since the server migration the information that gets requested is not longer being displayed on server A.

The javascript that server A uses to send the request can be seen below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">         
   jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      var ppUrl = 'http://www.nowgamernetwork.com/widgets/index.php?widget=popular&sourcetag=/other/&callback=jsonp1372412035546&_=1372412036723';
      jQuery.getJSON(ppUrl, function(data) {
          jQuery('.ipPopularPosts').append(data.content);
      });
   });
</script>
```

Interestingly, if you put the request URL into a broswer, it dislays the correct information.

```
http://www.nowgamernetwork.com/widgets/index.php?widget=popular&sourcetag=/other/&callback=jsonp1372412035546&_=1372412036723
```

But when the website requests this information, I get the following javascript errors:

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://www.nowgamernetwork.com/widgets/index.php?widget=popular&sourcetag=/other/&callback=jsonp1372416916349&_=1372416917575". jquery.js:3501

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < index.php:1
```

The error above relates to line 1 on index.php which can be seen below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">window.jQuery || document.write("<script src='http://www.nowgamernetwork.com/js/libs/jquery-1.5.1.min.js'>\x3C/script>")</script>
```

For some reason, Server A doesn't like the fact that the response it is getting from server C starts with a '<'.

How can I fix this problem?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Pass valid JSON, that should solve the problem, and if it's cross domain, valid JSONP ?

Comment: I shouldn't have to change any code, as it worked perfectly on server B. Now the code is hosted on server C, it has stopped working? Perhaps its a server configuration issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it.

The PHP script on server C was using 'ob_get_contents' to pull all of the html into a json format. I noticed ob_start was missing so I added that and it now returns that data in the correct format.

For some reason server B didn't require ob_start to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

- use &callback=?' in the url
- dataType: 'jsonp'

```js
(function($) {

var url = 'http://www.nowgamernetwork.com/widgets/index.php?widget=popular&sourcetag=/other/&callback=?';

$.ajax({

   type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    async: false,
    jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(json) {
       $(document.body).html(json.content)
    },
    error: function(e) {
       console.log(e.message);
    }
});

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src='http://www.nowgamernetwork.com/js/libs/jquery-1.5.1.min.js'>\x3C/script>
```

See the problem?

Comment: I shouldn't have to change any code, as it worked perfectly on server B. Now the code is hosted on server C, it has stopped working? Perhaps its a server configuration issue?

Comment: Okay, but im not sure `\x3C/script>` is valid